# Ho To Get A Role Of A User discord python

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm tying to add a command for specific users by role

I'm Trying This code

```
import os
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(command_prefix='.',intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('.start') and 'Premium' in message.author.roles:
      await message.channel.send("Server Is Starting")
    else: 
      await message.channel.send("You need a MOD role to use this command")

client.run('my token')
```

when i wrote the command in discord i got (You need a MOD role to use this command)

and when i try to test if i have the role by adding (`print(message.author.roles[1])`) i got (Premium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working through this, step by step:

- `message` is a [`Message`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Message).
- For messages sent within servers, `message.author` is a [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member).
- [`message.author.roles`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Member.roles) is a list of [`Role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Role)s, not a [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#list) of [`str`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str)s.
- All `Role` objects have an attribute [`name`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#discord.Role.name), which is a `str`.

Therefore, a fixed version of the code would be:

```
import os
import discord

intents = discord.Intents.all()
client = discord.Client(command_prefix='.',intents=intents)


@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.author == client.user:
        return
    if message.content.startswith('.start') and any(role.name=='Premium' for role in message.author.roles):
      await message.channel.send("Server Is Starting")
    else: 
      await message.channel.send("You need a MOD role to use this command")

client.run('my token')
```

Comment: ty a lot, now the code is working , my problem is i thought that (message.author.roles) was a list of role. thx

Comment: @MedCode That's great to hear! If this answer helped you, you should click the green checkmark to mark it as accepted. Welcome to Stack Overflow!